# How to interpolate data with Gnuplot for further calculations

Tags: gnuplot, interpolation

I am (somehow) familiar with the smooth/interpolation techniques in Gnuplot. It seems to me that these interpolations work only for plotting the interpolated values. However, I need the interpolated values for further calculations.

A simple example may illustrate this:
Let’s say we are selling a specific item on four days and have the number of sales stored in `input_numbers.dat`:

```
# days  |  number_of_sold_items
1   4
2   70
3   80
4   1
```

Now, I want to plot my income for each day. But the relation between the price per item and the number of sold items is not a simple linear relation, but something complicate which is only known for a few examples – stored in `input_price.dat`:

```
# number_of_sold_items  | price_per_item
1      5.00
3      4.10
10     3.80
100    3.00
```

How can I do something like this (pseudocode):

```
make INTERPOLATED_PRICE(x) using "input_price.dat"
plot "input_numbers.dat" using 1:($2*INTERPOLATED_PRICE($2))
```

I can do it by fitting but it is not what I want. The relation of the data is too complicated.

P.S.: I know that the price per item vs the number of items in such an example is more like a step-like function and not smooth. This is just an example for some interpolation in general.

Comment: you could try something like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009039/sample-linear-interpolation-of-data-file/53091217#53091217

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to prove the non-existence of something but I am pretty confident that this cannot be done with Gnuplot alone, as:

- I am under the illusion to be sufficiently familiar with Gnuplot that I would know about it if it existed.
- I cannot find anything about such a feature.
- It would completely go against Gnuplot’s paradigm to be a one-purpose tool for plotting (fitting is already borderline) and not to feature data processing.

Comment: Your point three is certainly true, but I´ve also made it a sport for me to show that gnuplot can do basically everything it *wasn´t* written for, too. ;)

Comment: Wrzlprmft, don't say that something can't be done with gnuplot. I agree with @Karl. Sometimes it might get lengthy, but most of the times there _is_ a gnuplot solution (see my answer, which is not too complicated). If possible, I prefer platform-independent _gnuplot-only_ solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Linear interpolation is not available, but how about this:

```
set xr [0:10]
set sample 21

# define an inline example dataset
$dat << EOD
0 1
2 2
4 4
6 5
8 4
10 3
EOD

# plot interpolated data to another inline dataset
set table $interp
plot $dat us 1:2 with table smooth cspline
unset table

plot $dat w lp, $interp w lp
```

Comment: I think that an explicit definition of `$dat` and `$interp` would improve this answer.

Comment: @alexis You mean like this?

Comment: Actually yes, I believe that helps for the first read. Thanks @Karl.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot can do something like this:

```
text = "%f*x + %f"

a = 2
b = 10

eval("f(x) = ".sprintf(text,a,b))

set grid x y
plot f(x)
```

which basically means that complicated functions can be defined dynamically: The `sprintf` command converts the text "%f*x + %f" into "2.0*x + 10", the dot operator `.` concatenates the strings "f(x) = " and "2.0*x + 10", and the `eval` command defines the function `f(x) = 2.0*x + 10`. The result can be plotted and gives the expected diagram:

[image: linear diagram]

This behavior can be used for creating a piecewise interpolation function as follows:

```
ip_file = "input_price.dat"
stats ip_file nooutput

n = STATS_records - 1
xmin = STATS_min_x
xmax = STATS_max_x

ip_f = sprintf("x < %f ? NaN : ", xmin)

f(x) = a*x + b # Make a linear interpolation from point to point.

do for [i=0:n-1] {

  set xrange [xmin:xmax]
  stats ip_file every ::i::(i+1) nooutput

  xmintemp = STATS_min_x
  xmaxtemp = STATS_max_x

  set xrange [xmintemp:xmaxtemp]

  a = 1
  b = 1
  fit f(x) ip_file every ::i::(i+1) via a, b

  ip_f = ip_f.sprintf("x < %f ? %f * x + %f : ", xmaxtemp, a, b)

}

ip_f = ip_f."NaN"

print ip_f  # The analytical form of the interpolation function.

eval("ip(x) = ".ip_f)

set samples 1000

#set xrange [xmin:xmax]
#plot ip(x)  # Plot the interpolation function.

unset xrange
plot "input_numbers.dat" using 1:($2*ip($2)) w lp
```

The `every` in combination with `stats` and `fit` limits the range to two successive datapoints, see `help stats` and `help every`. The ternary operator `?:` defines the interpolation function section by section, see `help ternary`.

This is the resulting analytical form of the interpolation function (after some formatting):

```
x < 1.000000 ? NaN 
    : x < 3.000000 ? -0.450000 * x + 5.450000 
    : x < 10.000000 ? -0.042857 * x + 4.228571 
    : x < 100.000000 ? -0.008889 * x + 3.888889 
    : NaN
```

This is the resulting interpolation function (plotted by `plot ip(x)`):

[image: interpolation function]

This is the resulting plot using the interpolation function in another calculation (`plot "input_numbers.dat" using 1:($2*ip($2))`):

[image: use interpolation function]

I don't know the limits on how many ternary operators you can nest and on how long a string or a function definition can be, ...

Tested with Gnuplot 5.0 on Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you are not looking for interpolation but for a lookup-table, i.e. depending on the number of sold items you have a different price.

What you can do with gnuplot is:

- (mis)using `stats` to create a lookup-string (check `help stats`)
- (mis)using `sum` to create a lookup-function (check `help sum`)

*Comment:*  I assume it will be a difference if you for example sell 3 times 1 item on a single day or 1 time 3 items on a single day, because of the graduation of prices.
So, I would suggest a different input data format, i.e. with a date.
(However, not yet implemented in the example below, but can be done. Then, you can make use of the `smooth frequency` option.) Some data format, e.g. like this:

```
# date       sold_items
2022-09-01   1
2022-09-01   1
2022-09-01   1
2022-09-02   3
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

```
### implement lookup table
reset session

$SALES <<EOD
# days  |  number_of_sold_items
 1    4
 2   70
 3   80
 4    1
EOD

$PRICE <<EOD
# number_of_sold_items  | price_per_item
   1   5.00
   3   4.10
  10   3.80
 100   3.00
EOD

LookupStr = ''
stats $PRICE u (LookupStr=LookupStr.sprintf(" %g %g",$1,$2)) nooutput
Lookup(v) = (p0=NaN, sum [i=1:words(LookupStr)/2] (v>=real(word(LookupStr,i*2-1)) ? \
             p0=real(word(LookupStr,i*2)) : 0), p0)

set grid x,y
set key noautotitle

set multiplot

    plot $SALES u 1:2 w lp pt 6 lc "dark-grey" ti "sold items", \
             '' u 1:($2*Lookup($2)) w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti "total income"

    # price table as graph inset
    set origin x0=0.41, y0=0.42
    set size   sx=0.30, sy=0.28
    set obj 1 rect from screen x0,y0 to screen x0+sx,y0+sy fs solid noborder lc "white" behind
    set margins 0,0,0,0
    set xrange [:150]
    set yrange [2.5:5.5]
    set xlabel "pieces" offset 0,0.5
    set ylabel "price / piece"
    set logscale x
    plot $PRICE u 1:2 w steps  lc "blue", \
             '' u 1:2 w p pt 7 lc "blue"
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]